# Ruby to Python3 conversion advice

Tags: python, ruby, python-3.x

for part of my project I am analyzing different algorithms to see the performance of multiple kinds of agents solving a game. I found a game to implement, however it is in Ruby and I am not very familiar with reading the code. I was wondering if you could help me out with this.

One class looks like this:

```
require 'io/console'

class Player
  attr_accessor :x

  def initialize
    @x = 0
  end

  def get_input
    input = STDIN.getch
    if input == 'a'
      return :left
    elsif input == 'd'
      return :right
    elsif input == 'q'
      exit
    end

    return :nothing
  end
end
```

And I believe I was able to successfully translate it into Python with this:

```
class Player:

def __init__(self, x = 0):
    self.x = x

def get_input:
    user_input = input("what direction? left = a, right = d, nothing = s")
    direction = 'nothing'

    if user_input == 'a':
        return direction = 'left'
    else:
        return direction  = 'right'

    return direction
```

However, there is another class called Game in Ruby and I am unable to be able to understand it well enough. Here's the code:

```
class Game
  attr_accessor :score, :map_size

  def initialize player
    @run = 0
    @map_size = 12
    @start_position = 3
    @player = player
    reset

    # Clear the console
    puts "\e[H\e[2J"

  end
…
```

I was wondering if you knew what the "def initialize player" line meant. Does that mean it's creating a Player? But then I'm not sure where the run variable fits into all this.

I appreciate all the help you can offer and I will be able to provide the full code for the Game class (it's only about 80 lines long) if need be. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby `def initialize` defines a constructor.  Ruby does not require parentheses for parameters if the meaning is unambiguous without them, so the Python equivalent would be `def __init__(self, player):` which defines a `Game` instance with `player` as an argument.  It looks like you already figured out to replace the `@`s with `self.`.

For your `Player` class, a more accurate translation for the constructor would be:

```
class Player:

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
```

The Ruby version doesn't allow you to specify `x` as an argument to the constructor, it hardwires the initialization to zero with no option to override that.

You might benefit from a quick glance at [this quick intro to Ruby for Python users](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/ruby-from-other-languages/to-ruby-from-python/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That actually makes a lot of sense... I would like to give you an upvote but I don't have enough reputation to do so (have 5, need 15). So we can have more than one __init__ function in Python?

Comment: In Python and in Ruby, each class defines its own constructor.  As @steenslag pointed out, the `def initialize player` line is defined for the `Game` class.

Answer (score 0):

The `def initialize player` is more readable for Python-trained eyes as `def initialize(player)`, which is also the usual way to write it in Ruby. it is not creating a Player, it is creating a Game instance, with "player" as argument.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So will the __init__ include score and map_size as well?

Comment: When you create a game instance with `Game.new("John" )` ,  ` @map_size` will be 12, so the method `map_size` (which is created by ` attr_accessor :score, :map_size` ) results in 12. `@score`  is not set however, so calling the method `score`  will result in `nil` .